# Mobile broadband not connecting

Tags: 10.10, internet

My BSNL CDMA 1x is detected in Ubuntu 10.10. When I am trying to connect with it (after required settings - user ID & password), after about a minute NetworkManager displays a message *"Network disconnected - You are offline"*. What may be the reason? Now I am working with the same device in Windows. I just installed Ubuntu 10.10 with Windows. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Please run this:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo NM_PPP_DEBUG=1 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --log-level=debug --no-daemon > ~/nm.out
sudo chown $(id -un) ~/nm.out
```

and then paste the contents of `~/nm.out` here.

Note that this file may contain your username and password, so please read it yourself first, and change any private details before posting if necessary.

Comment: After running 1st line I"d got the following result."unrecognized service".after 2nd line the result is-"access denied" .Please help me.

Comment: Change `/root` to `~`.

Comment: And it turns out the first line should be `network-manager` rather than `NetworkManager` on Ubuntu.  I have corrected by answer.

Comment: I got connection with a similar device of Reliance. 
Here I am pasting the result of ~/nm.out       but it will not fit here so i am pasting some portions about my BSNL modem.
NetworkManager[1949]: <warn> CDMA connection failed: (4) Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken. 
NetworkManager[1949]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: 4 -> 9 (reason 0) 
NetworkManager[1949]: <info> Marking connection 'BSNL connection' invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Just for info, though it may help, my mobile broadband needs a phone number and an APN but no user name or password is required

Answer (score 0):

I have "resolved" the  problem (ubuntu 11.04) removing network-manager-openvpn-gnome

BTW I need openvpn but still I've not found a solution.

[update] 11.04 has been fixed, the problem arises again in 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot  :-(